# ZSH, concatenate passed in arguments into a single string

Tags: bash, zsh, string, arguments, join

I would like to create a simple bash function to use for my convenience. Following the answer given at: [Joining bash arguments into single string with spaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197792/joining-bash-arguments-into-single-string-with-spaces) I've been able to mash up this small piece of code:

```sh
function gcm {
  msg="'$*'"
  eval "git commit -m ${msg}"
}
```

Now, this example is very convenient for commit messages like "Hello, it's me" (simple set of word characters that is), but when I wan't a commit message like: "[WIP] Halfway trough code.", I get an error message as follows: 
`zsh: no matches found: [WIP]`

Would you please clarify for me what is happening in the background and why this snippet fails?

Comment: Why eval? Just do git commit directly, double quote `$msg`, the problem gone

Comment: If you want to use square brackets in your strings, you might want to see the instructions on [THIS PAGE](http://kinopyo.com/en/blog/escape-square-bracket-by-default-in-zsh) and  [THIS PAGE](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-use-arguments-in-a-rake-task). I am not very familiar with zsh.

Comment: I pesonnally just have a `alias gc='git commit -m "'`
I just type `gc`, my message and end it by typing a double quote.
Unlike the function, it allows for multiline commit messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZSH is delightfully free of the word-splitting behaviour seen in other shells (unless for some bizarre reason the `SH_WORD_SPLIT` option has been turned on), so there is no need to use strange double-quoting constructs.

```
% (){ print -l $* } a b c  
a
b
c
% (){ print -l "$*" } a b c
a b c
% (){ local msg; msg="$*"; print -l $msg } a b c
a b c
%
```

Thus, the following should suffice:

```
function gcm {
  local msg
  msg="$*"
  git commit -m $msg
}
```

Globbing may be disabled by quoting strings like `[WIP]` as `'[WIP]'`, or perhaps via a `noglob` alias:

```
% function blah { print -l "$*" }
% alias blah='noglob blah'
% blah [de] *blah*
[de] *blah*
%
```

Comment: Very good. Almost done here. After following your advice, the snippet looks as follows:

 `function gcm {
  local msg
  msg="$*"
  git commit -m $msg
}
alias gcm ='noglob gcm'
`
This time, the error: _noglob gcm not found_

Pardon me for the poor formating, new to the forum =)

Comment: @33windowlicker When defining an alias there must not be any white spaces surrounding the `=`. So it needs to be `alias gcm='noglob gcm'`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know `zsh` had immediately called functions expressions !