# passing string containing spaces as command-line argument from within script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, quoting

I'm using a bash shell on mac.

I want to write a shell script 'gac' such that running

```
> gac one two three
```

produces *exactly* the same effect as running

```
> git add .
> git commit -m "one two three"
```

So far my script is this:

```
function gac() {
    git add .
    concatenated="'$*'"
    git commit -m "$concatenated"
}
```

I found the trick for concatenating the shell arguments into a single space-separated string (second line of script) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197792/joining-bash-arguments-into-single-string-with-spaces). The above script almost works, except that the log message reads

```
a382806 'one two three'
```

when I use my shell script, instead of

```
a382806 one two three
```

as when I manually type in

```
> git commit -m "one two three"
```

on the command line.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `'` characters in `"'$*'"` that you don't want to be there?

Comment: It seems this was closed as being about "a typo," which is not the case. Here, the OP **deliberately concatenated** `'` `'` with text generated by expanding a parameter. This also isn't a case of `'` `'` being used where `"` `"` is needed; *both* were used. I'm confident that this is a conceptual question, and I've [expanded my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399777/11938) to address it better, since it occurs to me that if close-voters did not recognize this, then novices who find this by searching may not either. This really shouldn't have been closed and I recommend reopening it.

Comment: by the way the git commit -am 'my message' does the same

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you place [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) around an [expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), such as the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `$*`, the expanded text is not subject to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting). (That's one of the reasons to use double quotes around `$` expansions; the other is to prevent [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion).) Furthermore, inside double quotes, [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) are not treated specially, so they do not perform quoting and they are not [removed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal).

So, as [Michael Homer says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399774/passing-string-containing-spaces-as-command-line-argument-from-within-script#comment713953_399774), you can just **omit the spurious  `'` `'` marks** and your function should work. I suggest writing it like this:

```bash
gac() {
    git add .
    git commit -m "$*"
}
```

You can use the `function` keyword to define functions in Bash but the syntax shown above works just as well and is portable across Bourne-style shells.

---

To address the conceptual issue here more directly, this line in your original code shows that you wanted to expand a parameter whose value contained spaces, in such a way that you could pass it as a single argument to `git`:

```bash
    concatenated="'$*'"
```

When you write a single argument yourself that contains spaces, you quote the spaces, usually with quotes around the whole string. The presence of `'` `'` *inside* the `"` `"` in that line tells me that you were trying to include the quotes that you would normally type.

The reason that approach does not work is that **the shell itself is what interprets your quotes; they don't typically mean anything to the command you run from the shell**. Suppose you have the command:

```
some-command 'foo bar' baz
```

That command does not actually pass any quotation marks to the `some-command` command. Instead, it runs `some-command` with `foo bar` as [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments) 1 and `baz` as argument 2. (There is also an argument 0, which tells a program how it was run; the shell passes `some-command` for that.)

Using quotes enables you to *tell the shell* where arguments begin and end. Spaces normally tell the shell to treat the text on each side as separate arguments<sup>**1**</sup>, but you want to suppress the spaces' special meaning to the shell, which is what quoting does. When quotes are quoted, like the inner `'` `'` inside `"` `"`, that removes *their* special meaning too. Then they don't perform quoting, but are instead passed literally to your command, as `git` showed in its log:

```
a382806 'one two three'
```

---

<sup>**1**</sup> [In the operation of the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation), spaces and tabs divide text into separate words in two related but distinct ways. First, [when a command is initially parsed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Syntax), unquoted spaces and tabs separate lexical tokens. Other [metacharacters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-metacharacter) do this, too, but they have additional effects--for example, `;` divides a line into multiple commands. Second, where [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) or any other [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) signified by a `$`<sup>**2**</sup> is performed in an unquoted context, the result is immediately subjected to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting), which [uses the characters in `$IFS` as delimiters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-IFS). The [default value of `IFS`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120578/11938) is a space followed by a tab followed by a newline.

<sup>**2**</sup> Or [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), even if the `` ` `` `` ` `` syntax is used instead of the `$(` `)` syntax.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I guess I should have looked a bit more closely at what I had copy-and-pasted from the other answer, I could have figured this out on my own :/

Comment: @Labrador Perhaps so. However, the fundamental issue here is that concatenating quote marks to the result of expanding a parameter does not have the intended effect, but instead passes the quote marks as part of the parameter. Thus the [problem being asked about there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197792/joining-bash-arguments-into-single-string-with-spaces) is not directly relevant to the problem you were trying to solve here. I've added a section to this answer that explains that specifically.

Comment: this is by far the best answer on this topic, as it actually links to the concepts old linux users assume are trivial